# PHP not kicking in for download files

Tags: php, forms, download, digital

I want to create a list for which my clients can choose a format of digital download then download the file.

[This](https://www.allphptricks.com/create-a-zip-file-using-php-and-download-multiple-files/) is exactly what I need but the php script isn't kicking any.

[https://finelinecreative/index.php/php](http://finelinecreative.co.nz/index.php/php)

Any ideas please? CMS is Concrete5 and I have all the correct server settings according to my host.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['files']))
{
$error = ""; //error holder
if(isset($_POST['createzip']))
{
$post = $_POST; 
$file_folder = "files/"; // folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
// Checking ZIP extension is available
if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
{ 
// Checking files are selected
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
// Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
foreach($post['files'] as $file)
{ 
$zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // Adding files into zip
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
}

}
else
$error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
}
}
?>
```

Server php version is 5.6
thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you're trying? Many people (myself included) would prefer to not click through to unfamiliar links.

Comment: You're asking a question like "see my car over there... it doesn't start. what's wrong with it?"

Comment: I see your point Daniel. Have provided php code - much more helpful.

Comment: You forgot to echo $error when it has been set.  Do that then edit your question to include the error.  If no error appears, tell us what F12 developer console says was sent by the server as the response.

Comment: Checked the PHP manual for ZipArchive add and looks like only suits PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 and PHP 7. I am on 5.6.